# Is the gauge fixing $\partial_\mu A^\mu + \gamma A_\mu A^\mu=0$ used in the literature and does it have a name?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, gauge-theory, gauge

In an exercise for a course on Gauge Theories, I was asked to derive the action of QED with the method by Faddeev and Popov, using the following gauge-fixing function:

$$F(A) = \partial_\mu A^\mu + \gamma A_\mu A^\mu, $$

where $\gamma$ is constant. I was wondering whether this function is simply a construction for the exercise or it is actually used in QFT, and how it is referenced in literature.

Comment: I'm surprised this is an admissible gauge condition.

Comment: @drake, how this function fails to be an admissible gauge condition? Please consider that I'm not familiar with gauge theories as this is my first course.

Comment: I'm not saying it is not. To know whether or not is admissible, one has to check that given an arbitrary $A$, there is a gauge transf. such that the new $A$, say $A'$, verifies the gauge condition. For example, $A^2=0$ is not a good gauge condition, except if $F=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By chance I stumbled on the paper [Diagrammar](http://cds.cern.ch/record/186259) by t' Hooft and Veltman and I found the same gauge fixing term in Section 11.3, as an example of a simple gauge fixing term that gives rise to Faddeev-Popov ghosts.

Moreover, the same gauge is used in Exercise 7.9 on Sterman's book, referencing a paper by Dirac: A New Classical Theory of Electrons (1951), but I don't have access to that paper.

Comment: For completeness, it is also worth mentioning that Itzykson&Zuber mention this gauge condition, and leave it as an exercise to the reader to check that it indeed leads to coupled ghosts (see below eq. 12-148).